# What is a "guest player" in GameKit?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit/gkplayer) for `GKPlayer` mentions a method for creating "guest players":

> The concept of guest players is introduced in iOS 9. Guest players are
>   treated exactly like authenticated players for Game Center multiplayer
>   purposes. However, guest players cannot earn achievements, post to
>   leaderboards, or participate in challenges. Create a guest player with
>   the [anonymous​Guest​Player(with​Identifier:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit/gkplayer/1520559-anonymousguestplayer) method.

But the same documentation says there must be an authenticated player before using GameKit. And indeed, pretty much everything GameKit fails if you aren't logged into Game Center.

So what is the purpose of "guest players" and how would you use them?

Answer (score 0):

its like : lets say your friend wants to play a game(that you also play) using **your** device. In that case your friend can directly play the game without effecting your scores and achievements if he plays as a guest. Its like a temporary way to play a game from someone else GameCenter account but without affecting his/her scores and achievements

Comment: How would you use a guest player in code? Could you provide an example in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

A guest player can be created even if there is no one signed in on the device at all.

```
let player = GKPlayer.anonymousGuestPlayer(withIdentifier: "123")
```

The identifier value does not really matter and will be available in `player.guestIdentifier`.

If a user is already signed into Game Center, the guest player will have an `alias` and `displayeName` of **"Guest of (`player alias`)"**. If there is no current Game Center user, they will be **"Guest of (null)"** :|

The guest player can be used for features throughout the game and it will have a gamePlayerID and a teamPlayerID just like regular signed in players.

You can even call `loadPhoto(for:)` on the guest player but the completion handler for this function is never called.

The purpose of this feature is unknown to me and there is no documentation for it.